# What resistor for uneven amount of LEDs in series, in parallel

Tags: led, resistors

I have an IR LED array which is powered by 12VDC. There are 10 chains wired in parallel. Each chain has 9 IR LEDs wired in series with a 10ohm 1/4 watt resistor. I also have 2 more chains wired in parallel, however these only have 6 LEDs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSrM6O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've used this tool to try and figure out an answer, but want to be sure I'm using the correct values: http://led.linear1.org/led.wiz
It does suggest using a 1 Ohm 1/4 watt resistor for the chains of 9, however I only have 10 Ohm as my minimum.

The LEDs have a forward voltage of 1.5V and a current draw of 20mA (to the best of my knowledge).

I want to calculate the correct resistance value to use for these shorter chains.

Comment: Please draw a schematic.

Comment: Thanks @winny, I've added one to the question. I hope that makes it more clear?

Comment: Nine of 1.5V LEDs need 13.5 V input nominal.

Comment: Upon measuring with my multimeter diode tester they are 1.14V. These were IR LEDs from eBay and I had just used the 1.5V from the webpage that I liked to. Looks like I need to swap to using 100 Ohms for the 9 LEDs and 270 Ohms for the 6 LEDs?

Comment: That’s not a schematic, but rather some variation of a fritzling connection table. There is a built in schematic editor here on EE.SE. Press edit on your question and press the schematic symbol and it will launch the editor.

Comment: That's a far better tool, thanks for that. I've again updated the question.

Comment: Vf rises 0.1V from 20 to 40mA then from self heating of 40’V , Vf drops 50mV. The 5mm IR can handle 50mA DC. So using a 1V drop from 25 Ohms should yield about 40mA

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist - so if I use the 100 Ohm resistors for the strips of 9, I don't know what you're saying to use for the strips of 6? Where do you get 40 volts from please?

Comment: Sorry typo +40’C rise from self heating (est.) and use 25 Ohms not 100, not 1 then verify if 1V drop or 40mA ( I recommend ) and adjust to get V/R=40mA then report back , forget 6S for now

Comment: https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/sunled/XTNI12BF/1497-1061-ND/4745876

Comment: The online calculator you have used is correct to the extent you provide it with correct data. The situation where the rated Vf * series elements will be close to your power supply rail will however be tricky since it will suggest very low resistance values and you might fry your LEDs here. Please measure the actual Vf of your LEDs in circuit with a known current and feed those values into the calculator. Play around with the supply voltage figure a bit up and down and see how much it influences the choose of R.

Comment: If I measure one of the LEDs, not connected using my Diode tester then I get 1.14volts. When powered on my existing circuit series of 9 LEDs with 12VDC and a 10 Ohm resistor, the Vf hovers around 1.3V (range is 1.29V up to 1.33V). Plugging in 1.3Vf into that tool gives me 15 Ohms for the series of 9 and 220 Ohms for a series of 6 LEDs. @TonyEErocketscientist - you are suggesting to up the values to 25 Ohms to allow for self heading? At the moment, 72 out of the total 102 LEDs are connected (8 strips of 9LEDs) and my bench PSU is reporting 170mA draw @ 12VDC

Comment: So you ended up with 30mA ? or 0.4V/10 Ohms =40mA? verify, so far ok.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Sorry, I'm not sure what points in the circuit to measure. The total current draw is actually 150mA (18.75mA per series of 9 LEDs with a 10 Ohm resistor)

Comment: Voltage drop across R gives you current.  I=V/R

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I setup a breadboard to make swapping resistor values easier. Tried a few values, and using a 15 Ohm resistor gave me a drop of 0.61V -> 40.6mA - that seems right? So if I swap out the 10 Ohm resistors for 15 on my circuit, I then need to play around with the 6 in series to get around the 40mA as well? Thanks again for your patience and help so far.

Comment: I've tried some values for the 6 series LEDs. 4.35V / 100 Ohms = 44mA, and 4.4V / 120 Ohms = 37mA - is it better to run the slightly lower current?

Comment: I am still assuming unless you state otherwise, that your LED's are similar to the datasheet I linked which shows 50 mA DC max. So either is acceptable.   Pay attention to R heat rating and temp.  Now we hope the supply voltage is stable but all is well so far.

Comment: This method is trial and error but at least is simple and is hopefully consistent on all strings as expected from LEDs from the same batch.  10% tolerance on desired current is acceptable. Now total current is 12 strings * ~40mA = 0.5A.  Although some inconsistent values were unclear at your Aug 22 9:00 comment with 140mA total or 12mA /string and 1.39V,  you can verify the V drop on each R value in each string to understand the tolerances on LEDs and can do this on your own now in future.    If you get wider tolerances, then alternative methods must be considered.